# Unable to implement Dialogflow Java SDK v2

Tags: java, android, authentication, dialogflow-es

**Question:
Could you tell me if there is a way to implement DialogFlow v2 on Android? If there isn't, could you tell me if there are plans for it to be supported in the future?**

Please find below what I am trying to do and how.

Goal: 
To implement the DialogFlow SDK v2 for Android, since currently only v1 is supported.

Problem:
Since DialogFlow v2 uses a Google Cloud Service account, OAuth2.0 authentication is required. However, after sending requests to the DialogFlow v2 URL using the access token obtained from methods outlined below , I received 403 errors.

What I tried:

1. While signed in to our Google account, I used the access token obtained during login to attempt a request.
2. In Google Cloud Platform, under "APIs & Services > Credentials", I created a new Client ID and obtained new access tokens via the following three methods. I then attempted requests using these three tokens.

   a. Using the obtained Client ID, I opened the following URL: 
   `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fadsense&response_type=code&access_type=offline`
   and obtained the authentication code.

   b. Using the authentication code, the Client ID and Client Secret, we refreshed and obtained the token using the below code.`curl --data "code=" --data "client_id=" --data "client_secret=" --data "redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" --data "grant_type=authorization_code" --data "access_type=offline" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`

   c. We obtained the access token from the Client ID, Client Secret and Refresh Token.

References:

- DialogFlow SDK: https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks

  - If you click on "See Quickstart" of the Java Ver. 2 Client Libraries, a 404 error is displayed.
- V1 & V2 comparison: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-comparison
- Authentication: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java#authentication
- Obtaining data with OAuth 2 authentication and without Web authentication from AdMob: https://qiita.com/go_sagawa/items/f38658e089e80dbe697e

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a log of your error list?

So far the things you did seem to be the right steps to solving the issue so I dont think it is related to DialogFlow.

Have you tried consulting the migration tutorial?

https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide

To answer your main question. **Yes DialogFlow V2 is implementable in Android. Follow the tutorial here**: [GitHub](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client#android-sdk-for-dialogflow)

Comment: This approach is using Legacy Sdk & Dialogflow V2 api. What I learned from Readme.md of https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/README.md, it says that android is not supported. Please check the Supported Platforms section in the ReadMe.md file

Comment: The question OP asked was about the implementation of the DialogFlow V2 API. I answered the question that was asked. The platform that you linked is not relevant to the question of the post.